# custom css and bootstrap css are not working

Tags: php, laravel

i just started a new laravel project. and it seems that bootstrap css is not working, as well with my custom css.

this is how i called the css :

```
<link href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('/css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and this is my whole page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laravel</title>

    <link href="{{ asset('/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('/css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Laravel</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

@yield('content')

        <!-- Scripts -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

anyone have solution for this?

Comment: is there any error shown in `console`?

Comment: @SapneshNaik there is no error

Comment: Check page source and make sure both CSSs are getting included correctly.

Comment: @ParthVora yes it's included when i check and opened in elements

Comment: ok, Can you please share your whole blade view?

Comment: Try to clear the cache and try again..

Comment: already added sir @ParthVora & i did clear the cache but the result is nada

Comment: @rinaldy31 inspect it with Firebug or whatever browser developer tools you use - see if the css is being applied but being overriden by anthing

Comment: Just a non-related suggestion: if you load `bootstrap.js` via a CDN you should do the same for `bootstrap.css` to make sure you're matching corresponding versions.

Comment: laravel includes jquery and bootstrap out of the box with mix, so it is probably colliding with it : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix

Comment: @apokryfos  sorry for the late reply, i tried what u suggested and used local. but still doesn't work

Comment: @Christophvh i tried local now, but still the same :(